# An appropriate antonym for "evolution"

Tags: word-request

[As we can see](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/evolution) there are many antonyms for the word **evolution**.

Please help me choose an appropriate antonym that would modify the word leadership. I need it as I want to translate into English the [following](http://adevarul.ro/news/politica/cozmin-gusa-despre-brexit-involutia-leadership-ului-european-genera-reactie-lant-1_576d4f4c5ab6550cb841a267/index.html) title of the article:

> Cozmin Gușă about Brexit: European leadership (**the requested word**) will generate a chain reaction

From the link I provided I'd pick up either **decline** or **devaluation** but I'm not sure. The word **regression** might do the job but I'm not sure either. Is it a good fit?

In my language would be easier as the perfect antonym of the word evolution is involution but its use in English (according to the on-line dictionaries) is limited to fewer fields such as: physiology, biology, medicine, etc.

I may have an additional question about the same evolution's antonym in case we can think of a language degeneration, or the so called degeneration would actually be an evolution too? So what would be the antonym for the language evolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard without knowing the context of the article, which I don't know how to read. Rather than point to a word you don't want, it might be worth circumlocution to describe what you do want to express.

**Devolution** comes to mind from sound alone, but that refers to power becoming more distributed after being centralized. Strictly speaking, evolution doesn't have a direction and so it won't have a direction-implying antonym as you are seeking. If you are looking for a word that means something like "going backwards to an earlier state", I would favor **regress**.

Answer (score 1):

***[Political involution](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=political%20involution&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpolitical%20involution%3B%2Cc0)*** is an expression that you can use:

Examples:

From : [Genoa and the Sea](https://books.google.it/books?id=CHQ8G2k9DAgC&pg=PA51&dq=%22political%20involution%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiD9ubMpo3PAhVGVRQKHbKDCvMQ6AEIGzAA#v=onepage&q=%22political%20involution%22&f=false):

> - ... in terms of amounts of money and in terms of numbers of people involved). This period was also one of ***marked political involution,*** during which...

From [South Africa's role in conflict](https://books.google.it/books?id=CpZ0AAAAMAAJ&q=%22political%20involution%22&dq=%22political%20involution%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjX_ujkp43PAhVBXRoKHWeIBfAQ6AEIKzAD) :

> - The past characteristics of the Congolese state - corruption, personalisation of power, and ethnicity - continue to prevail during this transition. The result ***is a process of political involution*** centred on a handful of rent- seeking cronies, leading to ...

Answer (score 1):

I would go for **weakening** in this context. The leadership of the EU is weakened by Brexit. I would also amend the word order to "The weakening of European leadership will generate a chain reaction…"

Comment: I appreciate your help.